# SWT label size is not correctly updated

Tags: java, swt

I'm new in Java/SWT. I'm experiencing some troubles using a [SWT label](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Label.html).

When I update the text on the label, its size is not correctly updated (the label is cut, respecting the original size). However, if I perform a very small resize in my dialog, the size is updated correctly.

Basically, I create the label with a default text and then, when I load data I update the label with the real text, that is bigger than the original one.

I tried calling `label.update()` and `label.redraw()` without luck.

Comment: It's more likely problem with layout. Which layout are you using? You should call layout recalculation if you expect label size change. Try to call `layoutInstance.layout(true);` method after you set new text to label.

Comment: Did you try `invalidate()/validate()` on container component?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to call `parent.layout()`, where `parent` is the `Composite` which contains your label. Also see [Understanding Layouts in SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. I'm used to Winforms. I need to do an effort reading about swt.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but in order to not lose any LayoutData settings that may be set on the controls.  You should call `getParent().requestLayout()`.  The documentation specifically discourages the user of `getParent().layout()` which loses all the cached Data settings on the controls.

Answer (score 1):

> Use of this method is discouraged since it is the least-efficient way to trigger a layout. The use of layout(true) discards all cached layout information, even from controls which have not changed. It is much more efficient to invoke Control.requestLayout() on every control which has changed in the layout than it is to invoke this method on the layout itself.

Based on the documentation of `getParent().layout()`, you should call `requestLayout()` on the control itself not its parent as @kingargyle said.

What I always did was `label.requestLayout()` and it worked flawlessly.