# How to refresh SWT label?

Tags: java, user-interface, label, swt

I built an `FileDialog` and after the user selects the file in it a label should be updated with the file name. This is what I have:

```
Button buttonSelectFile;
fileFilterPath = "C:/";
Label myDir;

fileSelectionLabel = new Label(container, SWT.None | SWT.WRAP);
fileSelectionLabel.setText("Path to file");

buttonSelectFile = new Button(container, SWT.PUSH);
buttonSelectFile.setText("Select file");
buttonSelectFile.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        Shell shell = new Shell();
        FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.MULTI);
        fileDialog.setFilterPath(fileFilterPath);
        fileDialog.setFilterExtensions(new String[] { "*.exe" });
        fileDialog.setFilterNames(new String[] { "exe-files" });

        String files = fileDialog.open();
        if (files != null) {
            fileFilterPath = fileDialog.getFilterPath();
            selectedFile = fileDialog.getFileName();
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(
                    "Selected file under directory "
                            + fileDialog.getFilterPath() + "\n");
            sb.append(selectedFile);
        }
    }
});

myDir = new Label(container, SWT.None);
new Label(container, SWT.None).setText("");
```

I tried calling `myDir.setText(fileFilterPath)` inside the `handleEvent()` method. Also tried to call `myDir.layout()`, `myDir.refresh()` and `myDir.getParent().layout()`. The label doesn't refresh.

How to refresh the label text?

Comment: What layout does `container` use?

Comment: @Baz org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite

Comment: That's the kind of widget, but what's the layout?

Comment: @Baz Sorry, it is GridLayout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calling `layout()` on the parent seems to work just fine here:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    final Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Click me!");
    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            label.setText(label.getText() + " test");
            label.getParent().layout();
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(400, 300);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

It's also the recommended solution here:

- [SWT label size is not correctly updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554922/swt-label-size-is-not-correctly-updated)
- [Java RCP - Not able to dynamically set text to SWT label control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862429/java-rcp-not-able-to-dynamically-set-text-to-swt-label-control)